# How can I get a hold of Minecraft's default textures?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Does anyone know how to get the default Minecraft textures? A download, maybe?

Answer (score 20):

The default textures are packaged inside the Minecraft .jar file, so you already have a copy. You can take a look at them with an unarchiver program that understands .jars (really, just zip-format files) such as 7zip, WinZip, etc. You'll find the .jar files in the `versions` folder of your Minecraft files.<sup>1</sup> If you look inside the .jar file, you'll find all of Minecraft's default textures in the `assets` folder.

You won't find these files online anywhere legitimate because it's not legal to distribute the files.

1. <sup>If you don't know where your Minecraft files are located, the easiest way is to start Minecraft, click **Options** then **Resource Packs**, then click **Open resource pack folder**. That will tell your OS to open the `resourcepack` folder. From there, go up one folder and you'll be looking at your Minecraft install, and `versions` will be one of the folders there.</sup>

Comment: You don't need 7zip or winrar or anything like that.  Literally just change the filename's extension from <something>.jar to <something>.jar.zip, and Windows File Explorer will treat it like a zipped folder.

Comment: I think this answer might be outdated now that there's the launcher.

Comment: @SephReed I don't think the location or the content of the Minecraft .jar file has changed since the new launcher, it's just a new launcher running the same old .jar file in the background.

Answer (score 2):

On a windows PC, hold 'Win+R' and type `%appdata%` This should automatically go to Roaming, but if not simply go to the roaming folder. Navigate to the .minecraft directory, and go to the 'Versions' Folder. Find the version of minecraft you are trying to make a texture pack for, and open it.

Create a Folder on your desktop, and copy the .jar and .json files into it. Make sure you copy. If you do not have a program like Win-Rar or 7-Zip, install one now. Right Click on the .jar and select 'Open With Win-Rar' or whatever your archiver may be. Delete META-INF, and go into the 'assets' folder. Change Whatever textures you like.

Once Finished, make a new folder in the versions folder called '1.x_resource1' or something. Paste the .jar and .json from your desktop into the new version, and select it from your launcher.

Answer (score 1):

You can download textures from multiple versions from the [mcasset.cloud](https://mcasset.cloud/) site, which is not affiliated with Mojang.

Answer (score -2):

Open your .minecraft folder (wherever it is), and then: versions > (Version you want here) > (Open .jar as archive) > assets

Comment: Assets aren't stored in the `.jar` file anymore.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It's just sounds that are not stored in there.